# How can I keep the integers after Parsing without losing the Readline data?

Tags: c#, console-application

The task is like that:
Write a program that reads days, hours, minutes and seconds from the standard input. Display the total amount of seconds.

Input:

> First line - d - days
>
> Second line - h - hours
>
> Third line - m - minutes
>
> Fourth line - s - seconds

Output:
On the only line of output, print the total amount of seconds.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int h = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int s = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        h = d * 24;
        m = h * 60;
        s = m * 60;
        Console.WriteLine(s);        
    }
}
```

This is what I managed to achieve, thank you for kindness if you reply ! :)

Comment: "How can I keep the integers" You did not loose the integers, but you lost their value.  .  When you want to keep another value (like `d *24`), you can store it in another variable, like `int HoursFromDays = d * 24;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Is your confusion perhaps because you're overwriting the values of h, m, and s with new ones? If you set `h = d * 24;` then you've told the compiler that you don't care about the value the user previously provided for hours, and you just want it to equal the days multiplied by 24.

Comment: If you want to keep some value, assign it to a variable and then don't assign something else to that variable later. If you want the result of `ReadLine`, assign it to a variable. If you want the number parsed from that `string`, assign it to a different variable. If you want the result of arithmetic performed on that number, assign it to a different variable again. It's pretty simple stuff. If you want to keep something, put it somewhere and don't replace it with something else.

Answer (score 1):

Let's extract *reading integer* routine as a method:

```
private static int ReadInteger(string title, Func<int, bool> validation) {
  while (true) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
      Console.WriteLine(title);

    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
      Console.WriteLine("Not an integer value, please try again");
    else if (validation != null && !validation(result))
      Console.WriteLine("Not a valid value, please try again");
    else
      return result;
  }
}
```

Then you can put

```
int d = ReadInteger("Please, input days", x => x >= 0);
int h = ReadInteger("Please, input hours", x => x >= 0 && x < 24);
int m = ReadInteger("Please, input minutes", x => x >= 0 && x < 60);
int s = ReadInteger("Please, input seconds", x => x >= 0 && x < 60);

long total = d * 86400L + h * 3600 + m * 60 + s;

Console.WriteLine($"{total} seconds in total.");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int h = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int s = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        d = (d * 24 * 60 * 60);
        h = h * 60 * 60;
        m *= 60;
        Console.WriteLine(d+h+m+s);
    }
}
```

This is how I managed to do it. Thank you guys for the replies! :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct code would be as below:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of Days: ");
        int d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of Hours: ");
        int h = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of Minutues: ");
        int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of Seconds: ");
        int s = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int t = d * 24 * 60 * 60 + h * 60 * 60 + m * 60 + s;
        Console.WriteLine("Total Seconds: " + t);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**
you need firstly to convert days to seconds: `d * 24 * 60 * 60`
and then hours to seconds: `h * 60 * 60`
and then minutes to seconds: `m * 60` and keep seconds as it is.
finally you need to sum all of this amounts to calculate total seconds.
I hope this helps.

Comment: And **why** is this "The correct code" ?  Please, explain that to whoever is reading this ...

Comment: I added an explanation to code.

Comment: Converting is already done in the question (see: `h = d * 24;`) (But, in order not to get a long discussion about it, I retracted the down-vote )

Comment: Ok, no problem. The point is you saved the conversion of day to hours in h and you overwrite what you read from user and so on. Sorry that it seems so clear to me .